Is it natural to say "I can still smell a hint of something"?
Say, I put on perfume and then I took a shower. Most of the perfume smell disappeared but some still remained.
Can I say "I can still smell a hint of perfume"?
Say, My baby pooped on my bed accidentally or several times a day. I didn't have time to change the bad cover so I cleaned it up. However, most of the poop smell was gone but some still remained.
Can I say "I can still smell a hint of baby poop"?
Can "a hint" be used for both bad and good smell?
If we can not use "a hint", what other words can we use?
a very small amount of something
Note: Most dictionaries do not say "a hint=faint smell", but "a hint=a very small amount of something".
Then, I heard someone (I am not sure is a native English speaker or not) say "smell a hint", so I just asked to make sure "to smell a hit" is a correct phrase.

A hint is a bit of a clue.  Not an obvious clue that would let you guess the right answer easily. The word  is used figuratively to mean "a faint indication".  The soap had a hint of cedar.

To call a faint smell of something a 'hint' (of that thing) is quite normal English. A hint of lavender, of smoke, of urine, of cheese, of perfume. Another very commonly used word is 'whiff'.

faint smell noun
These are words and phrases related to faint smell.
WHIFF
Synonyms
whiff, scent, odor/odour, aroma, bouquet, sniff, smell, breath, hint,
trace, soupçon

Synonyms of faint smell in English (Cambridge Dictionary)

I don't understand why someone gave me a down-vote. Most dictionaries do not say "a hint= faint smell", but "a hint=a very small amount of something". Then, I heard someone (I am not sure is a native English speaker or not) say "smell a hint", so I just want to make sure "to smell a hit" is a correct phrase.

Stackexchange also needs to build a function or text box where the people, who give a down-vote ,say clearly the reason they give a down-vote.

But you know a hint is a faint smell, so you could look for 'hint faint smell' on Google like I did.

Not my downvote, but I imagine the DVer figured either that you should have consulted a couple of dictionaries or that you should understand that words can be used figuratively and that one must be able to recognize analogical uses when you encounter them.

@TimR - not mine either, but I imagine that was the reason. Fot the record, I am completely opposed to any suggestion that up or down voters should be required to explain their action.  I think many questioners (and not just a few answerers) do not appreciate that the voting system on SE is not there to praise or chastise the individuals who ask or answer questions. It is more than that, and the site has an algorthm that makes upvoted content rise, and downvoted stuff sink, in listings. So voting is site curation, and conscientious voting is something people with sufficient rep should do.

I think the rep level to cast downvotes should be much higher than it is now.

I see I didn't spell algorithm correctly up there.

@TimR - it can get contentious - I have heard of downvote vendettas between users, although there are systems, apparently, in place to detect them. I tend to delete any of my answers that get a downvote to a negative amount that is not reversed by anyone else. There is such a thing as 'drive-by downvoting'. Quite a lot of interactive web sites attract people who are 'struggling with their mental health' as I think we are supposed to say these days, and many obsessives are that way about language.

@Tom The situations described in your questions are sometimes ultra specific, often slightly peculiar and a little out of the ordinary. Situations that are not typical and therefore not useful to your average learner. Saying that, your question is on topic but the DV could be due to the fact you mention cat faeces, which is an unpleasant topic, and it's not something cats normally, so why wouldn't you just wash the bedcover in the first place?  Any one showering shouldn't be able to detect any perfume (aftershave/deodorant/cologne) on their body but it might be possible I guess.

@TimR, "that you should understand that words can be used figuratively"??? No way!! English is hard, a learner should not predict a meaning that way! I am a non native English speaker and I often get wrong several times when predicting that way. That is why I want to ask real native English speakers to know the exact meaning. If a dictionary had at least one example like "I still smell a hit of the perfume", then I wouldn't post a question like this.

@Mari-LouA, actually that was baby's poop. A bed cover might have that incident of baby poop several times a day. My wife doesn't have time to change the bed cover several times a day

@Tom  Your beef was with the definition using the word "amount".  That strikes me as an overly literal approach to dictionary definitions. And there are four examples in the definition you cite, from which you should be able to glean that the word hint can be used figuratively, especially the winter example: The sauce has a subtle hint of garlic.
It was late March, but there was still a hint [=trace] of winter in the air.
He had a hint of a German accent.
They'll betray you at the first hint of trouble.
